# Split delimited string and store values in JSON object using dataweave

Tags: json, mule, datamapper, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I have a CSV file which sends records in the following format:

```
John,Smith,presentation|researcher|developer,js@email.com,07891234567
```

I need to take each record and map them to a list of the following JSON object:

```
[
   {
      "firstName": "John",
      "surname": "Smith",
      "skills": 
      [
         "presentation",
         "developer",
         "researcher"
      ]
      "email": "js@email.com",
      "phone": "07891234567"
   }
[
```

My problem is that how do you split the address text string and populate the address object along with the other fields using Dataweave and the Transform message component in Mule 3.8.1?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *splitBy* to get what you are wanting.

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/csv
%output application/json
---
payload map {
  firstname: $.firstname,
  lastname: $.lastname,
  skills: $.skills splitBy ('|'),
  email: $.email,
  phone: $.phone
}
```